# Spring MVC using @RequestParam with RequestMethod.DELETE on Tomcat 6.0.35

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-delete

I have a simple method (running on Tomcat 6.0.35) that looks like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bla/d", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void d(@RequestParam String d){
    //logic here
}
```

When I send a DELETE request with post like parameters (d=gggg in the body) I get a 400 Bad Request.
But if  I change it to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bla/d", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void d(@RequestParam String d){
    //logic here
}
```

It works perfectly.
I was using a Firefox Add-on to test it (and python and Spring's RestTemplate with same result) here's how the request look with POST(a is a cope pasted method named a with parameter a):

```
POST /bla/a HTTP/1.1
Host: ~~~~:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 7
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
a=asdas

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 09:29:46 GMT
```

And delete looks like:

```
DELETE /bla/d HTTP/1.1
Host: ~~~~~:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 7
d=asdas

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 971
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 09:30:04 GMT
Connection: close
```

Please help me, I might be missing something stupid but I just can't see it.
My original problem was sending an array via post-like body with DELETE request but it seems that something more basic is wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well after doing some research and debugging I've found out that Spring's ServletWebREquest calls getParameterValues of org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameterValues  which calls getParameterValues in which I've found the following line (Request.java 2599-2600):

```
if (!getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST"))
return;
```

Which kills any attempt to send POST-like parameters with DELETE which means Tomcat is actively restricts this use-case even though the RFC [does not restrict such usage](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-19#ref-Part6)(although it does say that some existing implementations may reject such requests, Tomcat just throws it's parameters away).
What brings one that's using Spring and Tomcat and trying to send a DELETE requests with parameters to ugly solutions like getting all the request body with @RequestBody and extracting it manually which makes your supposedly innocent method that just wants to delete something aware of some a Map that contains the request body.

@fmucar

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and the resolution that I found was to add the fields in the query string. I would still like to know the reasons why a form body would be excluded in this way, but for now this is a work-around.

So for your example it would mean adding
    ?a=asdas
to the Host: ~~~~~:8080 URL.

I am using spring-webmvc:3.2.4.RELEASE so I'm not sure if this will work in your version or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old post, but in case anyone else is looking for how to enable @RequestParam on DELETE methods, here's what I did on tomcat 8.5.4.

```
@Value("${server.parseBodyMethods}")
private String parseBodyMethods;

@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
            super.customizeConnector(connector);
            connector.setParseBodyMethods(parseBodyMethods);
        }
    };
}
```

Plug in 'POST,DELETE' to that customizer, and your delete request parameters should start working.

I found parseBodyMethods in org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector, and here is Tomcat's documentation on it:

> This is useful in RESTful applications that want to support POST-style semantics for PUT requests. Note that any setting other than POST causes Tomcat to behave in a way that goes against the intent of the servlet specification. The HTTP method TRACE is specifically forbidden here in accordance with the HTTP specification. The default is POST ([Source](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes))